# how to replace the zero values with the previous non-zero value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, subquery

Disclaimer: This is not a duplicate question. I have research before posting

[image]

The value in red circle should have "2" value, because the previous non-zero value is number 2. how to do that in mysql update query ? as you can see there are other rows that has the same zero value that needs to be having the previous non-zero value.

Comment: You have to use store procedures for this. You will have to write conditions in store procedure.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth: This has nothing to do with stored procedures.

Comment: Can we just not update and set `val1` as `2` where `val1 = 0`?

Comment: there must be a way to do this without using stored procedures

Comment: @juergend why it is not?? Since it is based on conditions , we can use stored procedure. It is not the only way.

Comment: @Sarques, the data is continuously pumping into that table. I need a query that will help me replace the zero values with the non-zero value of the previous record

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth can you please post your suggestion of strored proc and how to do it ?

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth: Yes it can be used. But there is no need to use it. And you wrote;: *You have to use store procedures for this*

Comment: @juergend my bad, have updated my comment.

Comment: The previous non zero value of a column is the one on top of it, right?

Comment: @tcadidot0 no, the non-zero is the previous row that is non-zero, ..please see the screen shot i posted. the zeros are in the red circle, both of their values should be 2 because the previous non-zero value is 2

Comment: Row .. I meant row.. xD.. Anyway, so for column `val3`, pk 13 should be 4 and pk 16 should be 7? Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an inline query:

```
select 
    pk,
    case when val1 = 0 
        then (select val1 from mytable t1 where t1.pk < t.pk and t1.val1 != 0 order by pk desc limit 1)
        else val1
    end val1,
    val2,
    val3,
    received_date
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to select the correct values use

```
  select pk, val1, @previous as previous_v, @previous := val1
  from your_table
  cross join (select @previous := 0) p
  order by pk
```

If you also want to update the table use

```
update your_table t
join
(
  select pk, val1, @previous as previous_v, @previous := val1
  from your_table
  cross join (select @previous := 0) p
  order by pk
) tmp on tmp.pk = t.pk
set t.val1 = previous_v
where t.val1 = 0
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b07f2a/1)